# Angular 2 ng2-uploader onUpload function is firing twice

Tags: angular

I am currently working with **ng2-uploader** and facing a serious problem when i upload a file it is firing twice the (onUpload):

**index.html**

```
  <input [ng-file-select]="options"(onUpload)="handleUpload($event)" type="file" >
```

**index.conroller**

```
handleUpload(data): void {
    console.log("on file");//console always shows twice

    if (data && data.response)
    {
      data = JSON.parse(data.response);
      this.uploadFile = data;
      this.editdata.file = this.uploadFile.filename;
      console.log('firing event->'+this.fireOnce);


  }
```

I don't know why it is calling two times after uploading the file this function fires twice but it should fire once as normal

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that clicking on it is firing multiple events. For instance, maybe it is firing a click event and a change event.

If you `console.log(data)` it might reveal the type of event being fired.

If I am right then you could do:

```
if (data.eventType === "click") {
    // your code
}
```

Obviously this code's syntax is wrong but you get the idea!

PS There are some useful facilities for watching what events are being fired.

For instance, in Firefox, if you execute:

```
monitorEvents($("input")[0]);
```

In your console, it will display all events being triggered which is really useful for debugging stuff like this.

Alternatively, if all else fails you could debounce the events so that your event handler function CANNOT be called again if it is called within one second of the previous call.

Comment: console.log(data) is showing [object object] and there is no function data.eventType

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(object))

Comment: also - the data.eventType is NOT the exact code - it is pseudo code to point you in the right direction - look for a similar property on the data object

Comment: using this one i am getting twice the same thing :{"id":"ovcqjv59f5s1qb5ha1yvi","originalName":"FitnessApp.docx","size":13034,"progress":{"total":13284,"loaded":13284,"percent":100},"done":true,"error":false,"abort":false,"status":200,"statusText":"OK","response":"{\"fieldname\":\"file\",\"originalname\":\"FitnessApp.docx\",\"encoding\":\"7bit\",\"mimetype\":\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document\",\"destination\":\"./uploads/\",\"filename\":\"file-1488531495832.docx\",\"path\":\"uploads\\\\file-1488531495832.docx\",\"size\":13034}"}

Comment: this is the second one:{"id":"ovcqjv59f5s1qb5ha1yvi","originalName":"FitnessApp.docx","size":13034,"progress":{"total":13284,"loaded":13284,"percent":100},"done":true,"error":false,"abort":false,"status":200,"statusText":"OK","response":"{\"fieldname\":\"file\",\"originalname\":\"FitnessApp.docx\",\"encoding\":\"7bit\",\"mimetype\":\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document\",\"destination\":\"./uploads/\",\"filename\":\"file-1488531495832.docx\",\"path\":\"uploads\\\\file-1488531495832.docx\",\"size\":13034}"}

Comment: even data.event and data.event.name is undefined

Comment: i suggest if you cannot get any event info then you just debounce this. debounce will stop it firing twice. debounce will say ... if it has fired once in last second then ignore any more calls. see lodash library for debounce. If you can, however, look for the issue that is causing it to fire twice.

Answer (score -1):

while looking all sources I didn't find any solution I just made a fix , here is my fixed code to firing it once:

```
fireOnce:Number; 
     constructor(){
         this.fireOnce=0;//initialized
               } 
     handleUpload(data): void {

           //the fucntion will still called twice but this condition will execute
 once so you can do your work in this if block 
      if(this.fireOnce==0)//ensuring this block to execute once 
     {
        //do your stuff here

            if (data && data.response)
             {
                data = JSON.parse(data.response);
                this.uploadFile = data;
                console.log('firing event->'+this.fireOnce);
           }
      }

      if(this.fireOnce==0)
      {
       //once fired never excute the above if block twice
        this.fireOnce=1;
      }
     }

  }
```

its just a cheat not the exact solution Hope angular 2 team will fix this bug soon